# Does an isogeny always define a covering map?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Consider a map $f: G_1 \to G_2$ between two topological groups.  If $f$ is an isogeny when viewing $G_1,G_2$ as algebraic groups does $f$ always define a covering map when viewing $G_1,G_2$ as topological spaces?  If yes could you give a proof and if not could you point out which is missing that disqualifies $f$ as a covering map? What if we restrict to Lie groups i.e. both $G_1$ and $G_2$ are Lie groups?

Comment: @Hoot: by Wikipedia an isogeny is a morphism of algebraic groups that is surjective and has a finite kernel.  That is why I mention "algebraic group".

Comment: Maybe you should just start off with algebraic groups then?

Comment: @Hoot: could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: I just mean that your first sentence leads me to believe that you think that a topological group can always be thought of as an [algebraic group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_group) in some natural way, and that's certainly not clear to me.

Comment: @Hoot: Let's make the question as simple as possible.  Suppose the groups qualify for both topological groups and algebraic groups.